# Validate required fields in dynamic WP form

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

So I'm creating a form using a simple array of fields:

```
    $fields = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Name:',
        'id' => $meta.'_nhm_lead_name',
        'class' => 'field-name input', // optional
        'wrapper_class' => 'four columns', // optional
        'type' => 'text',
        'required' => true,
    ),
    );
```

They are then echoed using a simple switch function like the one below:

```
    public function make_fields(){

    foreach($this->fields as $field => $value){
        switch ($value['type']) {
            case 'text':
                $inputs .= '<li class="field '.$value['wrapper_class'].'">';
                if($this->labels == true){
                    $inputs .= '<label for="'.$value['id'].'">'.$value['label'].'</label>';
                }
                $inputs .= '<input type="text" name="'.$value['id'].'" class="'.$value['class'].'" />';
                $inputs .= '<span class="error-message"></span>';
                $inputs .= '</li>';
            break;
        }
    }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that when I POST them to my post handling form, I have no way to verify if they are required and what kind of field they are. How would I go about this? Also this is a form thats built for Wordpress.

Comment: Maybe you can add hidden field which have data of all required fields. Then on server side you can map it. Not good approach from security view though.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on client side.

```
public function make_fields(){

foreach($this->fields as $field => $value){
    $required = "NULL";
      if($value['required'] == "yes") {
            $required = 'required="required"';   
        }
    switch ($value['type']) {
        case 'text':
            $inputs .= '<li class="field '.$value['wrapper_class'].'">';
            if($this->labels == true){
                $inputs .= '<label for="'.$value['id'].'">'.$value['label'].'</label>';
            }
            $inputs .= '<input type="text" $required name="'.$value['id'].'" class="'.$value['class'].'" />';
            $inputs .= '<span class="error-message"></span>';
            $inputs .= '</li>';
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How would I check that on the server side now?

Comment: For that i have added comment to your question.